# Concurrent insert into entity collection

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have bidirectional mapping between `Family` and `Person`:

```
@Entity class Family {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "family", ...)
    Set<Person> persons;
    ...
} 

@Entity class Person {
    @ManyToOne
    Family family;
    ...
}
```

My problem is that I can concurrently add and/or remove elements from the collection, which it breaks atomicity in the updates, as adding a new person creates `INSERT INTO Person ...` statement that does not collide with the other insert. `@Version` field does not help, since I am not updating the `Family` entity as row in the table, just logically.

What should I do to enable only atomic updates of the collection? I have tried loading `Family` with `LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`, which can synchronize the updates on the `Family` itself, but that does not allow second-level caching for the read of `Family`. I would prefer optimistic transactions with kind of predicate constraint in the DB.

Comment: Therefore you have to use transactions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-optimistic_force_increment-lock-mode-work/):

```
entityManager.lock(family, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
```

This way version will be checked and incremented in the corresponding `Family` entity instance.

**EDIT**

Since you are using L2 cache, and for some reason (bug, design decision, or just a missing feature) Hibernate does not update the version in the L2 cache after the force increment, you will have to actually load the entity with this lock for everything to work properly:

```
entityManager.find(Family.class, id, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
```

However, now you will have to take care to be consistent and to load the `Family` entities this way always prior to updating them (to avoid working with stale version values because L2 cache is not in sync with the database).

To overcome this, you could add an artificial column to the `Family` entity, like `lastUpdateTime` or something, and update the `Family` instance without using any explicit lock. Then the regular version check would occur and everything would be synchronized with the L2 cache.

Comment: It seems that this works, though I am getting some locking timeouts from DB (H2 1.3.176) now... I'll mark that as correct once I figure out what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look why L2 does not notify the cache. Currently I am still trying to fix L2 Infinispan implementation, as there are some consistency issues when using clustered cache.