# Why does OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT not increment the version in 2nd-Level-Cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a parent-child-relationship where the parent holds the @version property and it should be incremented whenever the parent itself or any of it children changes.

```
@Entity class Parent{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", ...)
  Set<Child> children;

  @Version
  int version;
} 

@Entity class Child{
  @ManyToOne
  Parent parent;
}
```

To archive this I lock the parent in OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT mode, whenever I add, modify or delete a child.

```
entityManager.lock(parent, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
// modify child
```

Immediately before the transaction completes, hibernate generates a statement like this

```sql
/* forced version increment */ update
    "PARENT" 
set
    "VERSION"=? 
where
    "PARENT_ID"=? 
    and "VERSION"=?
```

The version in the database is correctly incremented whereas the 2nd-Level-Cache doesn't get updated. If I select the parent it will be loaded from 2nd-Level-Cache and I still get the old version, I could do a refresh on it or evict it from 2nd-Level-Cache, but it doesn't feel right, it just has to be updated in consistency to the database.

I tried Infinispan and EHCache which both behave the same so I think it is a hibernate problem.

This is also the reason, why the RootAware-pattern from Vlad Mihalcea is not working in combination with 2nd-Level-Cache. See https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-increment-the-parent-entity-version-whenever-a-child-entity-gets-modified-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31003719/9354242
As I in this comment suggested I added a @LastModifiedDate column to the parent and update it whenever I modify a child. Instead of OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT I will have to use just OPTIMISTIC as LockModeType and it is working, both 2nd-Level-Cache and database have the correct version number, but I don't think this is a very good workaround since every developer has to know about it and there is a huge probability someone somewhere will forget it. Also it is a bad thing to add such a column like this just as a workaround.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What is your cache strategy for the `Parent` class? Could it be READ_ONLY? Try adding a Cache-annotation

```
@Cache(usage = READ_WRITE)
@Entity
class Parent
```

... to your entity and see if situation improves!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is READ_WRITE, i omitted it in the example

Comment: Hmm... Going for guesswork here: What if you modify your `Child` class and add a `@Cascade(LOCK)` annotation on the parent property and play with locking on the child instead?

Comment: It's not a problem with the locking, the locking actually works, it's just the update statement on the version number at the end of the transaction which bypasses the 2nd-Level-Cache if no other property of the parent except the Version itself is changed. It seems the only way to fix this is to just manually change a random property - like the LastModifiedDate i mentioned.

Comment: I would recommend filing a bug at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/ together with a minimal project to reproduce the problem...